# What is $P_{ij}$ in this context

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, physics, mathematical-physics

**For context:**

This problem arose when attempting to implement the Lanczos algorithm for putting a matrix into tri-diagonal form in order to find the ground state energy and first excited state energy for a 1D spin chain.

**The problem:**

I will preface this question by saying that I'm am aware that given a permutation $\pi$, that we can find a permutation matrix $P_{\pi}$ with elements defined by

\begin{equation} 
p_{ij}= 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \pi(i)=j\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}. 
\end{equation}

Now, according to my notes we can write the matrix $P_{ij}$ as,

\begin{equation}
P_{ij}=2\vec{S_i}\cdot\vec{S_j}+\frac{1}{2}I=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

where $\vec{S_{i,j}}$ are $2\times 2$ spin matrices. According to my professor (and here is where my doubts begin),

\begin{equation}
P_{01}\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ x_2 \\ x_1 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

That is, we permute elements $1$ and $2$. My question is, should we not be permuting elements $0$ and $1$, since the matrix is $P_{01}$, and not $P_{12}$.

My professor then goes onto state that the Hamiltonian for a 1D spin chain can be written as $$H=\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\vec{S_i}\cdot S_{i+1}\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}P_{ij}-\frac{L}{2}I\bigg).$$ I suppose my trouble with understanding this, is that I have no idea what $i,j$ are supposed to represent. If anyone can explain what $P_{ij}$ actually is, that would be appreciated.

Comment: As for the second thing, at a quick glance it looks like a prototypical two-particle interaction Hamiltonian: each particle contributes something to the Hamiltonian based only on its own state, and each *pair* of particles contributes something to the Hamiltonian based on the interaction between them. I don't know what $\cdot$ means in this context, though (matrix multiplication? elementwise multiplication?)

Comment: Regarding the first thing, that looks like a typo to me. The only other possibility I can see is that there is some jumbling going on where $P_{ij}$ is defined to be the thing you get when you use the spin matrices $S_i,S_j$, which is in turn not actually permuting $i$ and $j$. But that sounds exceedingly unlikely compared to the possibility of a typo.